# Getting file resource from Jar in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, configuration

I am trying to run a Hadoop application from a jar:

```
hadoop jar myJarFile.jar my.class.path.Here /path/to/input /path/to/output
```

In one of the classes in myJarFile.jar, I am attempting to read a resource from the classpath thus:

```
public void init() {
    Configuration conf  = new Configuration();
    conf.addResource("resources/myConf.xml");
    log.info("Data element=" + conf.get("data.element"));
    ....
```

In myJarFile.jar, resource/myConf exists:

```
[prompt] jar myJarFile.jar
my/class/path/Here.class
...
resources/myConf.xml
```

and the configuration file contains the name/value pair in the proper (Hadoop-style) format. However, whenever I try to run this, it fails to find the myConf.xml file, even though it should be on the classpath.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the init method belongs to either mapper or reducer class. JVM executing these classes are not the same JVM as driver program and potentially on different machine altogether. So you cannot read local file system from those classes.

You have two options to read this file.

**Option 1 (preferred) Use Distributed cache like this:**

```
JobConf job = new JobConf();
 DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("resources/myConf.xml"), 
                               job);
```

Now this file you can use in mapper or reducer init method like this:

```
File f = new File("./myConf.xml");
```

**Option 2 (not preferred) : Upload file in HDFS and read using HDFS java client api.**

```
 Path pt=new Path("hdfs://<hdfs hostname>:9000/user/john/myConf.xml");
                    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
```

The reason why this option is not preferred is because for each record that you are mapping or reducing, you are reading data from hdfs so you will have major performance issues.

Comment: I tried this, getting the file, and then passing it to addResource(). But that does not work. I also tried getting the resource in the job setup stage (in the driver's run() method, before setting up the Job object). But neither of these is reading the resource.

Comment: Correction: I tried adding the path of the file to addResource(). Should the new File() line be new File("resources/myConf.xml")? What do I pass to the addResource() line?

Comment: Just curious why are you trying to add a resource to configuration in init method (of mapper or reducer)?

Answer (score 0):

OK - turned out my original code actually works (except for some later bugs...) But my deployment script had accidentally omitted the actual xml file, and I missed it because there was a similarly-named properties file.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I am still curious why do you want to add resource to config in init method?